# fromtimestamp returns me Invalid argument

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to convert an int variable (timestamp) to datetime but django returns me fromtimestamp Invalid argument

```
date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.data["time"]))

Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: What value are you passing through `.fromtimestamp()`?

Comment: It's an integer. I solved the problem by dividing this value by 1000, converting my variable to millisecond (ms). It was in second (s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by dividing int(request.data["time"]) value by 1000, converting my variable to seconds(s). It was in milliseconds (s)

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.data["time"])/1000)
```

Comment: It's the other way around. You are converting milliseconds to seconds by dividing by 1000. ( 5000ms / 1000 = 5s) `datetime.fromtimestamp` expects a unix timestamp in seconds (usually seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC).